# Application time setting

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a web application.. When a user want to register with that application Local time of that user must be registered in this application.. I tried to get the browser time to register ..It is working ..Now i want to improve this.. The user can have incorrect time in his system... SO i need a solution to solve this problem.. Any suggestion.. Pls share with me..

Answer (score 1):

What about [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx)? That property always returns server time.

Comment: based on the application user location we insert the date into DB.. So i need to get the date & time based on the application user

Comment: Allright clear. What if you get the javascript timezone (-d.getTimezoneOffset()/60) and the calculate with the server time with DateTime.Now?